# Coloring Zoomable Treemap

Tags: d3.js, treemap

I am using this treemap.
http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/treemap.html.

Here every group gets a different colour assigned. I want the same thing except , in every group I need the color to range from its dark shade to light shade depending upon value in the json.

I have tried many things but it did not work.

How to go about this ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Tree Map Code

```
    var w = 1280 - 80,
    h = 800 - 180,
    x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, w]),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h]),
    color = d3.scale.category20c(),
    root,
    node;

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
    .round(false)
    .size([w, h])
    .sticky(true)
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var svg = d3.select("#body").append("div")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .style("width", w + "px")
    .style("height", h + "px")
  .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(.5,.5)");

d3.json("flare.json", function(data) {
  node = root = data;

  var nodes = treemap.nodes(root)
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; });

  var cell = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "cell")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });

  cell.append("svg:rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return d.dx - 1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy - 1; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.parent.name); });

  cell.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.dx / 2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("opacity", function(d) { d.w = this.getComputedTextLength(); return d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

  d3.select(window).on("click", function() { zoom(root); });

  d3.select("select").on("change", function() {
    treemap.value(this.value == "size" ? size : count).nodes(root);
    zoom(node);
  });
});

function size(d) {
  return d.size;
}

function count(d) {
  return 1;
}

function zoom(d) {
  var kx = w / d.dx, ky = h / d.dy;
  x.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);
  y.domain([d.y, d.y + d.dy]);

  var t = svg.selectAll("g.cell").transition()
      .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; });

  t.select("rect")
      .attr("width", function(d) { return kx * d.dx - 1; })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return ky * d.dy - 1; })

  t.select("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return kx * d.dx / 2; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return ky * d.dy / 2; })
      .style("opacity", function(d) { return kx * d.dx > d.w ? 1 : 0; });

  node = d;
  d3.event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you want do you want within the group all should have a different lighter color?

Comment: @Cyril With in a group, the cell with higesht value shoud have darker color and cell with a smaller value should have a slighlty lighter and so on up to lowest value. With in a group , it should be something like ths . [link]( https://www.google.co.in/search?q=tableau+heat+map&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbwMCD3cnJAhVDrJQKHSiDBS4Q_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=tableau+tree+map&imgrc=2ErOkGarOHRJBM%3A )